# jQuery html() function on future element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. When the user selects something specific in a dropdown that loads an external document which includes some additional fields like so

```
$( "#morefields" ).load( "partials/formadditionals.jsp", function() {
    ...
});
```

This "formadditionals.jsp" contains a title `<h1 id="form2title"></h1>`.
Now after that has loaded I want to write something into that `<h1>` via

```
$('#form2title').html("Test");
```

...which does not work, I am assuming because the element did not exists before!?

How can I use the `html()` function on "future" elements after they are loaded into the DOM?

Comment: If the element was appended to the document prior trying to query it it should work. Can you post the code inserting the content?

Comment: `$('#form2title').html("Test");` goes insiide 'function() {
    ...
});' right?

Comment: use event delegation for future elements : https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Yes, the $('#form2title... should go into the function! That worked!

Comment: @Kentoro Calling `.html()` is not an event.

Comment: Just put `$('#form2title').html("Test")` inside the callback function... You wrote a callback function, use it :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe, i didnt meant it was either, i'm loggin out now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Call it in the callback function.

```
$( "#morefields" ).load( "partials/formadditionals.jsp", function() {
    $('#form2title').html("Test");
});
```

Shameless plug: http://curtistimson.co.uk/jquery/using-jquery-callback-functions/

Comment: @Silvanmidix you should read into callbacks and promises. It's a very powerful paradigm making use of javascripts async nature.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, because the element isn't yet in the DOM, calling `$('#form2title').html("Test");` doesn't do anything.  In the callback function for the load function, you can make these sorts of calls because that element now exists in the DOM.

```
$("#morefields").load("partials/formadditionals.jsp", function() {
    $('#form2title').html("Test");
});
```